# DIV height like having some text inside

Tags: html, css

On one of my web pages I have a DIV element, containing string of text inside, which is of, say, 1.1em size. For example:

```
<div id="displaydiv">
    <b>Hello World</b>
</div>
```

Another page has the same DIV element, but with no text inside it at all. And that's why this DIV has the visual height of less value than the one on the first page.

```
<div id="displaydiv">

</div>
```

What is the recommended way of keeping the DIV element on the second page of the same height as on the first one?

Comment: @rem: Do you want it to be 1.1em? Or do you want it to be the height of the other one on another page? Or do you want it to be at least some height? Could you be more specific?

Comment: First of all I'd like it to be the height of the other one on another page.

Comment: if there's no content in the `<div>` on the 2nd page, why not just remove it?

Comment: @jnpcl There is a background color in the div. I need all this to make the design consistent

Comment: @rem: What about setting `min-height` ?

Comment: @jnpcl Maybe. Didn't think about it. For this very case the @Justin's proposal about using `&nbsp;` fits well. But `min-height` can be useful in some other cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting an `&nbsp;` inside.

If the page is dynamically generated and your template language supports conditionals, make sure only to show the `&nbsp;` when there's no content.

Otherwise, if you can't show it only when empty, to avoid messing up your text alignment (thanks to [@bensiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367878/bensiu) for pointing this out), stick the `&nbsp;` at the end of the string (or beginning if the text is right-aligned). If it's center-aligned, you can put an `&nbsp;` on both ends.

Comment: I think this is better than any css options, because it most accurately reproduces the desired height in any situation.

Comment: Take notice, after your last edit the `&nbsp;` disappeared from the first line of your post. This makes your very useful suggestion hard to read. Please, correct it.

Comment: @rem - nice catch! not sure what happened-- perhaps there's an error in round-tripping escaped characters? in any case, it should be fixed now, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: What happens on multiline text?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="displaydiv" style="height: 1.1em">

</div>
```

and nbsp; also is patch solution, because you need to remember to take it off when you got text inside and not ruin you aligment

Comment: Yep, nbsp; is a hack solution but it's often the easiest and works easiest across browsers and element types (inline vs. block). Assuming the page is dynamically generated, it's easy to show the nbsp; only when there's no content. You can also stick it at the end of the string (or beginning if the text is right-aligned). If it's center-aligned, you can put an nsbp; on both ends.

Answer (score -1):

If you would like it to be the same height as on the other page, you could do this by passing a parameter to the next page, like with `$_GET` in `PHP`.

You could use jQuery to exactly measure the height of your div (with [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/)). Then, when going to your new page, you should do something like: `myDomain.com/newPage?height=500`. Use PHP to evaluate your new height in the new page.